# Android project vanished from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am doing Android Development using:

Eclipse 3.7.0
ADT 16.0.1

I believe I was trying to undo something so I clicked on Ctrl-Z or Apple-Z (don't remember), and my whole android project completely vanished from Eclipse. The whole project folder disappeared, all the files were closed. Eclipse was still on though.
I looked in the workspace and the trash but the folder wasn't there. I searched all of my computer and didn't find any trace of it.

Do you happen to have any idea of what could have happened? And what can I do to recover my files?

Comment: From your question, it looks your PackageExplorer or ProjectExplorer window got closed. your project is safe.

Answer (score 1):

try Edit->Undo Delete Resource
NOTE: It will only work if you haven't closed your eclipse..

Once I have same problem but I have backup of project..
Next time plz keep your backup of project in one folder or directory...

Answer (score 0):

Try this Windows->Show View ->Project Explorer

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi @Creator,  I tried that and all it does is bring up the Project Explorer window. My project is still gone. It's not even in the workspace folder where all my projects are. It seems to have been deleted from my computer once and for all (it's not even in the trash!). It's very strange.

Comment: Then take help of the data recovery softwares, if the projects are not in workspace. If that fails, you need to create the project from scratch again, there's no other option. The reason I thought of is, you might be using any beta version of eclipse, which was unstable, even if its a full-release version, eclipse always have some bugs in it. May be it was the hard way to teach you why backup is important.

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried Ctrl+Y to redo the changes or Ctrl+Z again??

Comment: Hi @Creator, Yes I tried Ctrl+Z but nothing happened. Oh well. thanks for your advice. The first thing I need to do is probably install some software version control. Do you happen to know of a good one that integrates well with Eclipse and Android SDK??